# RazorEngine - How to use a complex model view?

Tags: razorengine

Anyone have experience working with a complex model and RazorEngine?

Working on generating HTML using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) version 3.7.3, but running into issues with the complex model view we have.  It seems like we should be able to use the templates to get RazorEngine to discover the SubSample below, but have not discovered the proper way to tell RazorEngine about the associated cshtml file.

In the example below we are looking to use a shared template for the SubSample class using the SubSample.cshtml file.  As can be seen from the results, the class namespace (ReportSample.SubSample) is displayed rather than an HTML row of data.

We have tried implementing an ITemplateManager, but Resolve() is never called with a key asking for the SubSample.  Also tried AddTemplate() on the service, but still no joy.

Here is a simplified example model to illustrate the issue:

```
namespace ReportSample
{
    public class SubSample
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SampleModel
    {
        public SubSample SubSample { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SampleModel.cshtml**

```
@using ReportSample
@*@model ReportSample.SampleModel*@
<table style="width: 7.5in" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <h1>
                Sample Report
            </h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b>Name:</b> @Model.SubSample.Name
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b>Value:</b> @Model.SubSample.Value
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <h1>
                Sub-sample Data
            </h1>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                @Model.SubSample
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**SubSample.cshtml**

```
@model ReportSample.SubSample
@using FSWebportal.Infrastructure.Mvc;
<tr class="observation-row">
    <td class="observation-label">
        @model.Name
    </td>
    <td class="observation-view">
        @model.Value
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Basic RazorEngine calls:**

```
private void html_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gen = new RazorEngineGenerator();
    var cshtmlTemplate = File.ReadAllText("Sample.cshtml");

    var sample = new SampleModel() { SubSample = new SubSample() { Name = "name", Value = "value" } };

    var html = gen.GenerateHtml(sample, cshtmlTemplate);
}

public string GenerateHtml<T>(T model, string cshtmlTemplate)
{
    var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
    using (var service = RazorEngineService.Create(config))
    {
        return service.RunCompile(cshtmlTemplate, "", typeof(T), model);
    }
}
```

**Sample HTML Output:**

## Sample Report

**Name:** name
                        
                        
                            **Value:** value

## Sub-sample Data

ReportSample.SubSample

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't think I fully understand your question but I have a small idea of what you are trying to do...

I think what you want are searching for are partial templates (using @Include)!

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;
using System;

namespace TestRunnerHelper
{
    public class SubModel
    {
        public string SubModelProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public string ModelProperty { get; set; }
        public SubModel SubModel { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = Engine.Razor;
            // In this example I'm using the default configuration, but you should choose a different template manager: http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateManager.html
            service.AddTemplate("part", @"my template");
            // If you leave the second and third parameters out the current model will be used.
            // If you leave the third we assume the template can be used for multiple types and use "dynamic".
            // If the second parameter is null (which is default) the third parameter is ignored.
            // To workaround in the case you want to specify type "dynamic" without specifying a model use Include("p", new object(), null)
            service.AddTemplate("template", @"<h1>@Include(""part"", @Model.SubModel, typeof(TestRunnerHelper.SubModel))</h1>");
            service.Compile("template", typeof(MyModel));
            service.Compile("part", typeof(SubModel));
            var result = service.Run("template", typeof(MyModel), new MyModel { ModelProperty = "model", SubModel = new SubModel { SubModelProperty = "submodel"} });
            Console.WriteLine("Result is: {0}", result);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added documentation for this here: https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/LayoutAndPartial.html

However I think making `@Model.SubSample` work is possible as well, you can either change the SubSample property to be of type `TemplateWriter` or make the SubSample class implement `IEncodedString`. But I think you should consider partial templates first!

Comment: I saw your code, and wrote a working unit test based on the code.  One suggestion:  use "@Model.SubModelProperty" vice "my template" for "part" to make it clear one can reference the SubModel.

Comment: We are trying to avoid the need for the `@Include` syntax.  We have quite a few chtml files already being used by MVC code, so using `@Include` would mean having to pre-parse the code to add `@Include`.  We are hoping to get the engine to discover the proper template similar to how MVC is able to discover shared templates.

Comment: A 'magic' discovery engine is not supported currently by RazorEngine. As mentioned in the question you can only do workarounds by modifying the model instead of the template (changing the types of the properties or make them (here the SubModel class) implement IEncodedString).